# 404 error while import js file from another folders in index.html in nodejs + Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have error and am trying to solve it for hours.
My file structure:

```
-/node_modules
-/www
---bundle.js
---index.html
```

in index.html I have such code

```
<script src="node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Problem is `bundle.js` is included fine, but `ng-cordova.min.js` gives `404` error

```
Cannot GET /node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js
```

**Edit**: I also tried this without success

```
<script src="/node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I don't use `express` or `express.static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your project structure I'm betting that it is powered by [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/). I'm also betting that the `www` folder was set as a static folder in the express app like this:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, www)));
```

In which case your server will only serve files located in the `www` folder. You need to include any client dependencies in the `www` folder:

```
-/node_modules/
-/www/
--lib/
---ng-cordova/
--bundle.js
--index.html
```

And then load them like so:

```
<script src="lib/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

Simply put node_modules inside the `www` folder, it should work fine.

Comment: I thought express.js is something you should use directly and I don't use it so I didn't thought in this direction.

Comment: But when I `require` modules in my `app.js` it works fine. Why is it so?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Just updated my answer. I use express a lot so I just assumed that you are using it too when I saw the node_modules folder. Simply put node_modules inside the www folder, it should work fine.

Comment: I am a little confused because I use `npm` and it created folder `node_modules`, so I can't simply move it. And I think `node_modules` are now in the right place.

Comment: You could simply run `npm install` inside the `www` folder.  From what I gather from your code and project structure, your http server is serving static files from the `www` directory only. Please correct me if I am wrong in assuming so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you try to load your ***ng-cordova.min.js*** file from the ***index.html*** folder.
You should change:

```
<script src="node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For this:

```
<script src="../node_modules/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load the file from the wrong directory.
You either have to use this path:

```
src="../node_modules/
```

or this:

```
src="/node_modules"
```

in case the above directory is your root directory.

What's also confusing is that the line you commented the error in is not the line the error actually comes from. Why are you trying to link to the file twice?

//Edit: As Romain was a minute faster than me he deserves the right answer reward I'd say :P Only if it actually solves your problem ofc :D

Comment: Have you installed any other node module you could test loading a js file from?

Comment: Yes, I have several other modules and no one is loading such way. I use for them `browserify`, this module also works fine with `browserify`.

Comment: Sorry for not getting your answer but are the other modules loading or not?

Comment: I tested other modules and they don't loading in index.html. Same error.